# Multithreading - Does this new design cause any data races?

Tags: multithreading

I figured it would be a lot easier if I drew a picture of my problem. Here it is:

[image: Design]

Everything that is black in the diagram is part of the old design. Everything that is blue is part of the new design. Basically, I need to add a new thread (Worker Thread C) that will handle most of the work that Worker Thread B used to do. Worker Thread A is listening for real time updates from an external application. When he receives an update, he posts a message to Worker Thread B. Worker Thread B will set its copy of the new data (he still needs it in the new design) and then notify the GUI Thread as well as Worker Thread C that new data has arrived.

The user will send a request from the GUI to the new thread (Worker Thread C). Worker Thread C will process the request using the last received copy of the data that originally came from Worker Thread A. So my question is: Will Worker Thread C always be using the latest copy of the data when processing a request with this new design? What if Worker Thread B is too slow to update and then the user submits a request from the GUI? Thanks!

Comment: This won't work. You need to ensure that worker thread B sends the (copy of the) update to worker thread C *prior* so sending the update to the GUI. (Even so, this is close to a working design.)

Comment: Thanks Mankarse. How can I ensure that worker thread B receives the update (if there is one) before the GUI sends a request to worker thread C?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, worker A is conceptually different than workers B and C, right? It rather looks like B and C handle user requests in the background in order to not block the UI. So, there could be a whole list of these background workers that perform UI operations or even none, while there will always be a worker A that pulls/receives updates.

Now, what I would do is that the worker A sends new data to the UI. The UI then uses this data in the next request. When it starts one of the workers like B or C, it just passes the data along with the other info that tells the thread what to do.

Note that you need to take care that you don't modify the data in different threads. The easiest way is to always copy the data when passing it between different parts, but that is often too expensive. Another easy way is to make the data constant. In worker A, you use a `unique_ptr<Data>`  to accumulate the update and then send that data as a `shared_ptr<Data const>` to the UI thread. From that point on, this data is immutable (the compiler makes sure that you don't change it by accident) so it can be shared between threads without any further lock.

When creating a worker for a background operation, you pass in the `shared_ptr<Data const>`. If it needs to modify that data, it would first have to copy it, but usually that isn't something that can't be avoided.

Notes:

- The basic idea is that you have either shared and immutable data or exclusive-owned and mutable data.
- The data received from thread A is stored in the UI here, but conceptually it is part of the model in an MVC design. There, you only keep a reference to the last update, the earlier ones can be discarded. The worker thread still using the data won't notice, because the data is refcounted using shared_ptr.
- At some point, I would consider aborting the background workers. Computing anything based on old data is not necessary, so it could be worthwhile to not waste time on it but to restart based on recent data.
- I'm assuming that the channels between the threads (message queues) are synchronized. If they are already synchronized, that is all that you need.
- If you're using C++98, you will need auto_ptr instead of unique_ptr and Boost's shared_ptr.

Comment: Hi Ulrich. Yes, that's correct. I guess maybe "worker thread" isn't quite the right term for all of these threads. These threads are always around. They aren't spawned dynamically or anything like that. The issue is that I can't change the architecture of all of this. In other words, the process flow must be that A sends the update to B initially. After that, I need to figure out how C can get the update reliably before user sends a request to C. It seems like the only way I can do is to post an event to B, grab the data copy there, and then post an event to C. I don't like that design though.